# Get Raw HTML from controller in textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I want to get raw html in text box. My html is written in controller and i want to get in bootstrap modal within a text box.
 i am using loop if $data have 4 values it makes textarea 4 times but i want only once,

here is my code ..
**Controller**

```
$string  = '';
foreach ($students as $student) {
        $type = $student->type;
        switch($type) {
            case 'classA':
                $data = "<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor ClassA</p>";
                break;
            case 'ClassB':
                $data = '<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor ClassB</p>';
                break;
        }

        $string .=    '<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">HTML
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-icon right">
                            <i class="fa"></i>
                            <textarea name="html" class="form-control" rows="8">'.$data.'</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }
    return $string;
```

Now here need to return `$string` if i returns it within loop bracket it gives data but makes textbox 1 for each value while i want all data in only one textbox.
 thanks

Comment: write $string  = ''; statement outside the foreach loop.. in loop it will get initialise every time to blank.

Comment: thanks @pAsh its giving output how can i get it only in one text box?

Comment: you want to $data + $string content in one text box?

Comment: You want to show the string output in texbox? Why ?

Comment: Not @pAsh i have $data variable i want to show it in textarea this time if i have 4 or 5 values in $data it gives values in 4 or 5 textboxes but i want all $data in only one textarea

Comment: i update my question also

Comment: for that you have to write that $string ="html" below the foreach loop. like $data = '';foreach(){ $data.="html"} $string = "html".$data."html" ; return $string;

Comment: please can you give it in answer more clear Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer :

```
$data = '';
    foreach ($students as $student) {
            $type = $student->type;
            switch($type) {
                case 'classA':
                    $data .= "<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor ClassA</p>";
                    break;
                case 'ClassB':
                    $data .= '<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor ClassB</p>';
                    break;
            }


        }
          $string = '<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">HTML
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="input-icon right">
                                <i class="fa"></i>
                                <textarea name="html" class="form-control" rows="8">'.$data.'</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
        return $string;
```